# dplyr fails to summarize

Tags: r, statistics, dplyr, time-series

My data frame is a time series with different variables and looks like

```
Date    prcpmm  TmaxC   TminC
1/1/1966    0   7.8 0
1/2/1966    0.8 8.3 -1.1
1/3/1966    0   2.8 -5
1/4/1966    0   4.4 -5.6
1/5/1966    0   5.6 -8.9
1/6/1966    0   2.2 -1.7
1/7/1966    0.5 0.6 -12.8
1/8/1966    0   -6.1    -15
1/9/1966    0   3.9 -8.3
1/10/1966   0   5   -8.9
1/11/1966   0   -5  -12.2
1/12/1966   1   -3.3    -11.1
1/13/1966   1.3 2.2 -6.1
```

starting from 1966 - 2005, link to have an access to the input file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B09Gj4L5FPQWeGt0Wl94OWVlelE

I tried the blow mentioned code:

```
Adrian <- read.csv("~/Adrian.csv")

Adrian <- cbind(Adrian, weatherGen = rep("ObservedAdrian", nrow(Adrian)))
dateObj <- as.POSIXct(Adrian$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

Adrian$Date <- dateObj
Adrian$day <- day(dateObj)
Adrian$month <- month(dateObj)
Adrian$year <- year(dateObj)
Adrian$prcpmm[Adrian$prcpmm==-99.00]<- NA
Adrian$TmaxC[Adrian$TmaxC==-99.00]<- NA

Adrian$TminC[Adrian$TminC==-99.00]<- NA

for (i in 1:length(Adrian$month)) {
 if (Adrian$month[i] %in% 3:5) {
 Adrian$season[i] = "spring"
 Adrian$yearNew[i] = Adrian$year[i]
 } else if (Adrian$month[i] %in% 6:8) {
 Adrian$season[i] = "summer"
 Adrian$yearNew[i] = Adrian$year[i]
 } else if (Adrian$month[i] %in% 9:11) {
  Adrian$season[i] = "fall"
  Adrian$yearNew[i] = Adrian$year[i]
 } else{
  Adrian$season[i] = "winter"
  Adrian$yearNew[i] = Adrian$year[i] + 1
 }
}
Adrian$season <- ordered(Adrian$season, levels = c("winter", "spring", 
"summer", "fall"))
```

It executed till this part very well without error.

```
 Observed_everyseason_pVal <- Adrian %>% group_by(yearNew, season) %>% 
 summarise(pvalMK = mk.test(ts(prcpmm))$pvalue[1], SMK = 
 mk.test(ts(prcpmm))$Sg[1] )
 Observed_everyseason_pVal1 <- Adrian %>% group_by(season) %>% 
  summarise(pvalMK = mk.test(ts(prcpmm))$pvalue[1], SMK = 
  mk.test(ts(prcpmm))$Sg[1])
```

from the above to code lines:

```
Observed_everyseason_pVal <- Adrian %>% group_by(yearNew, season)
```

It worked well without error but when I run with

```
  Observed_everyseason_pVal <- Adrian %>% group_by(yearNew, season) %>% 
   summarise(pvalMK = mk.test(ts(prcpmm))$pvalue[1], SMK = 
   mk.test(ts(prcpmm))$Sg[1] )
```

It produces error:

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :  Column `pvalMK` is of
>   unsupported type NULL

Comment: it seems to be saying that the output of the function you are applying is null, which is not NA. It might mean that `mk.test` is not available in your working environment (a library might need loading) or they data is not in the right format for the function so it is throwing a Null return value. Try running your group_by and saving it in a variable, looking at the output with `str(myGroupby)` to see how it looks. If the data is appropriate for the function in summarize, then try doing traditional operations using `mk.test(ts(prcpmm))$pvalue[1]` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do `str(mk.test(ts(Adrian$prcpmm)))`, it gives you the following output:

```
List of 9
 $ data.name  : chr "ts(Adrian$prcpmm)"
 $ p.value    : num 0.259
 $ statistic  : Named num 1.13
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "z"
 $ null.value : Named num 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
 $ parameter  : Named int 13
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "n"
 $ estimates  : Named num [1:3] 16 176.67 0.28
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "S" "varS" "tau"
 $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
 $ method     : chr "Mann-Kendall trend test"
 $ pvalg      : num 0.259
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

Therefore, the former object you specified, namely `mk.test(ts(prcpmm))$pvalue[1]`, doesn´t exist. There is only `mk.test(ts(prcpmm))$p.value[1]`. Also, the object `mk.test(ts(prcpmm))$Sg[1]` (`...$Sg`) is not in scope at all. This explains the error: `Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Column pvalMK is of unsupported type NULL`.